# compare user input with database using php oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm passing this t2 value in last page here I use to compare with db value but only first echo is working, not else part.

```
$t2=$_REQUEST['t2'];
$stid =oci_parse($conn, "SELECT USERNAME,ACCOUNT FROM PEOPLE where    USERNAME='$login_session' ");
oci_execute($stid);
 while($r = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)){
  if($t2 < $r['SALARY'])
      echo("yes");
     else
  {
  echo("no"); 
  }
 }
oci_close($conn);
```

I have checked there is no problem with getting session value also. But don't know what's the real problem.

Comment: sorry i forgot to change this  if($t2 < $r['ACCOUNT']), please find me solution.

Comment: Try printing value of $['ACCOUNT'] and $t2 in while loop before if statement.  And check if both values are there in variable or not.